# Clicking two buttons to open a component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm doing a project for my students and the idea is that when clicking the button1 (Red) plus button2 (Blue) the component with the color Purple appears.

[Demo]https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wave-cosuw?file=/src/App.js

two butttons : btn1 and btn2, when clicked on both opens the component test.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import Test from "./Test";
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [showComponent, setComponent] = useState(false)
  const show = () =>{
    setComponent(true)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Click in two Buttons open a component Test.js</h1>
      <h2>Sample</h2>
      <div>
        <button onClick ={() => show()} id="btn1">btn1</button>
        <button onClick ={() => show()} id="btn2">btn2</button>
        {showComponent && 
          <Test/>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The intention was good but I would like to know if there is a possibility to open the component only when the two buttons are clicked, regardless of the order, here in your example when I click on a button it already opens the component.
Is it the case here to make a condition? If btn1 is true and btn2 is false it does not open, but if btn1 is true and btn2 is true opens the component, does this make sense?